# Linq Groupby and OrderByDescending can't be translated in .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm migrating my application from .NET to .NET Core. However, the .NET Core 3.1 application reports `OrderByDescending(x => x.Time)` can't be translated while it works fine in .NET framework.

How could I fix this issue?

```
var prevlist = _db.Botstatus
                  .Where(x => x.Time < starttime && x.Status != null)
                  .GroupBy(x => x.deviceId)
                  .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.Time)
                  .FirstOrDefault())
                  .ToList();
```

[image]

Any suggestion would be appreciated! Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: `OrderByDescending + First` = `Max`?

Comment: You are currently using EF Core. Which version of ORM have you used before: Core or EF 6?